# Logout not working in Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I have been using JMeter for a while and I am facing a problem in particular related to logout. I am using the below script -

```
TestPlan
    HTTP Cookie Manager
    HTTP Request Defaults
    ThreadGroup - (scheduled for half and hour)
        Once Only Controller
            HTTP Request - login
        Loop Controller - (forever)
            HTTP Request 1
            HTTP Request 2
            ....
            HTTP Request 13
    tearDown Thread Group
            HTTP Request - logout
```

But the problem here is that even the logout response looks good , the user used for JMeter script login is still actually not logged out. (that i can monitor as as Admin)

Comment: How do you verify the success of logout request? Have you used any response assertion? or are you reading response in tree view mode manually?

Comment: You need to first analyze what could be expected response for a successful logout request and then use response assertions. So jmeter will give you failure error when ever that assertion will not be met.

Comment: I suspect from the plan you posted, that since your logout is on a different thread group, than the rest of your operations, it won't have the same cookies as login, so it just won't do anything. You either need to save cookies as parameters, so you can reuse them in a different threads, or change your logic so that logout is executed int he same thread group

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your "Logout" link just clears user's cookies via JavaScript. As per [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) project main page:

> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time).

So Logout event can be simulated in JMeter by clearing cookies - see "Clear cookies each iteration" box in the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar)

[image: HTTP Cookie Manager]

NB: Iteration in the HTTP Cookie Manager (as well as in HTTP Cache Manager, etc) is something which is being defined and incremented at [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level, loops triggered by Loop Controller, While Controller, etc. are not considered as "iterations"

It it also possible to clear cookies programatically i.e. from [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler)